# LCD substitute for 7-segment LED display?

Tags: 7segmentdisplay, character-lcd

For a project of mines, I use a 7-segment LED display, the [SA52-11EWA](https://uk.farnell.com/kingbright/sa52-11ewa/display-seven-segment-17-5mm-red/dp/1168589), common anode. All OK, but the display is poorly visible outside, under the sun. Very annoying.

So I thought to use an LCD display instead but, strangely, it seems no simple 7-segment + decimal point exist. That type (single digit + DP) is very common in LED version, while it seem there is no counterpart in LCD version. I've even found LCD displays with 2 digits and 2 DPs, that seem to have the decimal points in the wrong position.

Does somebody know whether such 7-segment LCD display exists? Actually I need 2 digits, so a single panel with 2 digits (and 2 DPs) would be also ok.

-- Please note: I am not asking for a specific product or a place to buy. The question was and still is "do such kind of product exist?". --

Comment: You just want a single character LCD display? I would doubt there would be much use for a part like that so it'll be unlikely that you find one

Comment: @mcg: TY... ok, even 2 digits would be ok, but no more.

Comment: See answer below

Comment: This seems like a shopping question, and therefore disallowed, doubly so when you get upset about suggestions that do not meet size requirements you didn't bother to state in your question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton well, I understand. Perhaps you didn't fully understand. I would like to delete this question, but I can not because there is an answer that says that I should use parametric search, and the results of that search is something I already found and refused (using.. guess what?), and in one case I also mentioned it in the question.

Comment: This is not explicitly a shopping question, but if would be required that people answering the question to "go shopping" and search suppliers or distributors to answer it, therefore, it is off topic. The decision to make shopping questions off topic was made by Jeff Atwood the founder of stack exchange. If you need to ask these questions, use the chat YMMV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stand corrected on my comment under the question.

Searching through the parametric search on Digikey, you could use this: https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/lumex-opto-components-inc/LCD-S101D14TR/67-1506-ND/286956

This is a 1x1 digit LCD display with decimal point.

As for a 2 digit display, yes, these also exist, such as this one: https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/varitronix/VI-201-DP-RC-S/153-1003-ND/2375

Again, this was found with the parametric search on Digikey. This satisfies the 2 digits and 2 DP requirements.

Parametric searches are a great tool, places such as Digikey, Farnell, Mouser etc all have this function. To get the results I did, I just searched "7 segment LCD" then changed the parameters of the search (such as no. of characters). Using these search tools is something you should practise and get used to as it really is useful when trying to find a part to fit a specific need.

Comment: Hi mgc, I don't know whether you read my previous comment, quickly deleted by someone. Anyway I'm going to do what I promised.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica I did see your comment. I don't know if you saw my reply as that was deleted too. I clarified that I was just trying to be thorough and was in no way meaning to have a tone, hence why I think the downvote on it wasn't warranted

Comment: no, I couldn't see your reply. I think that we would have find a good agreement if left alone, and in fact I promised to accept the answer in a short time. But someone else got in the middle, and messed all up. In the end, this page is a good job for this site (irony intended).

Comment: I've noticed there has been some strange moderation and comment deletion going on lately.  Haven't yet checked meta, but something weird is going on, like disappearing comments that appeared to be relevant to the initial question...

Comment: As people  are asking here and on meta - 2 comments have been deleted (not by me). The 1st by the op I would have considered deleting if I'd seen it on two points. The other - not by the OP - was reasonable but was related to the first comment so made less sense in isolation.

Comment: Note: To whom it may concern - a downvote means "this answer is not useful" - downvoting it shows a lack of understanding of the answer, at least.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I agree my response comment was related to the original comment so would not have made much sense on its own. The downvote I believe it was also to do with the comment as it was mentioned in there. I'm unsure whether mods can see deleted comments though!

Comment: @MCG Moderatorss can see deleted comments. My comments above are made in that context. I thought your comment and answer were well within the range of acceptable :-).